# import 'dart:html' is Failing

Tags: http, dart, libraries

I'm trying to get use `HttpResponse.getString()` to fetch some data but I can't get it to import. I'm using the Dart VM.

I've tried

- `import 'dart:html'` which gives me `Error: Not found: 'dart:html'`
- `import 'package:http/http.dart` but this package does not have the `HttpRequest` class
- `import 'dart:io'` which has the class but not the `getString()` method

Here is my code

```
void main() async {
  Future<String> data = HttpRequest.getString('localhost:8000');
  print(data);
}
```

Why can't I access this class and method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you running your program?

- `dart:html` is only available for applications running inside a browser.
- `package:http` is not the same as `dart:html` and does therefore have other classes. But you can achieve the same by using that package.
- `dart:io` is only available when running your application by the Dart VM. But you can use this to achieve the same but you need to write the code differently.

Since you get the error `Error: Not found: 'dart:html'` I assume you are trying to get this working in the Dart VM.

You can do it like this if you want to use the `http` package which I think it the easiest way to get what you want:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> main() async {
  Future<String> data = http.read('localhost:8000');
  print(await data);
}
```

And if you want to use `dart:io` it can be done like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final clientRequest = await HttpClient().getUrl(Uri.parse('localhost:8000'));
  final clientResponse = await clientRequest.close();
  final data = await clientResponse
      .transform(const Utf8Decoder())
      .fold<StringBuffer>(
          StringBuffer(), (buffer, element) => buffer..write(element));
  print(data.toString());
}
```